# UK transit visa and USA visit visa

Tags: uk, transit-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

I am from Bangladesh and I  am visiting the USA in December. Is there any way I can get a transit visa for the UK and stay there for 4-5 days, before I go to the US?

Answer (score 8):

A *Visitor in Transit* visa for the UK allows only stays of less than 48 hours. For a 4-5 days visit you need to apply for an ordinary *Standard Visitor* visa.

If you're traveling to or from USA with a valid US visa, you may qualify for landside *Transit Without Visa* in the UK, but only if there's at most one midnight coming between your arrival and departure, so it doesn't work for 4-5 days.